# How to declare a binary array in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, variables, declaration

This question might be pretty simple to answer, but I had problems finding obvious answer in the numpy documentation.

What is the dtype to select when initializing a binary numpy array as follows:

```
array = np.zeros(8, dtype=np.int)
```

Comment: Can you explain how this is not "binary enough" for you?

Comment: Were you looking for `.packbits` ? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html

Comment: @mkrieger1 I assume that the integer declaration takes more memory or am I wrong with that?

Comment: More memory compared to what?

Comment: @mkrieger1: I just checked and sys.getsizeof(array) returns 128 bytes for dtype=np.int vs. 104 for dtype=np.bool or np.dtype('b').

Answer (score 8):

You can use np.bool:

```
array = np.zeros(8, dtype=np.bool)
```

output:

```
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False])
```

Comment: `np.bool` is deprecated, use `array = np.zeros(8, dtype=bool)`